# How to draw a straight dashed line across chart at zero

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to draw a straight dashed line across my linear chart at zero.

I got it to work by drawing another series with all the points on the y axis at 0 and it works ok but I would like to change the style to 'Dash' and also remove the annoying series name it adds to the legend by default. I don't want it to appear in the legend. I tried setting name to '' for this part.

```
        var zeroSerie = {
            data: firstSeries,
            dashstyle: 'Dash'
        };
        zeroSeries.name = '';
        soarChart.addSeries(zeroSerie, false)
```

[image]

I would also very much like to set the colour to red and 'stroke-width': 2,

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

I think that is better to use the `plotLines` option:

```
yAxis: {
    plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        color: 'red',
        zIndex: 2,
        dashStyle: 'dash'
    }]
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zan69hm7/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.plotLines

Comment: @ppotacek -  Nice example. Doesn't work for me, unfortunately. I'm not sure why. I'm using highcharts 6.1.0. I also tried to apply it programmatically and doesn't work either.

Comment: Hi @user1472672, Please try to set `width`: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/efwujv72/

Comment: I got it to work using the addPlotLine method. So thanks!